# Getting 404 in Laravel Horizon assets

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-horizon

I am trying `Laravel Horizon` for demo and for installing I followed the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/horizon) and everything worked for me perfectly until I got this error in console: [image: this error in console]

I have also publish my vendor using this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Horizon\HorizonServiceProvider"
```

Wonder what I've missed?

Comment: Are you using virtualhost?

Comment: nope I'm not using virtual host.

Comment: What occurs if you run `php artisan horizon` ?

Comment: I got message Horizon started successfully.

Comment: And when you got this errors ? I mean what command you run and got this errors of assets?

Comment: when I tried to run horizon on on /horizon as mentioned in docs after php artisan horizon

Comment: still the same thing..

Comment: This defines in docs: `Horizon exposes a dashboard at /horizon` So i think it's running on `/horizon` url!

Comment: got 404 if I run just /horizon I haven't adjust .htaccess

Comment: Thinking on this have you tried the obvious.. `../` before the  app.css and app.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running the server with `php artisan serve` and checking on `http://localhost:8000`

Your url is targeting the folder `public` since you don't use a VirtualHost, and I think the problem can be the current url on the browser

Comment: yeah I got that on laravel server `localhost:8000` but I am still confused why I got this problem why I'm not able access via `public`? and how can I access via `/public`?